# Factory to create NGRX actions based on a string

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

assuming I have the following actions

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

import { Skill } from '../../models/skill.model';

export const LOAD_SKILLS = '[Skills Section] Load Skills';
export const LOAD_SKILLS_FAIL = '[Skills Section] Load Skills Fail';
export const LOAD_SKILLS_SUCCESS = '[Skills Section] Load Skills Success';
export const CLEAR_SKILLS = '[Skills Section] Clear Skills';

export class LoadSkills implements Action {
    readonly type = LOAD_SKILLS;
}

export class LoadSkillsFail implements Action {
    readonly type = LOAD_SKILLS_FAIL;
    constructor(public payload: any) { }
}

export class LoadSkillsSuccess implements Action {
    readonly type = LOAD_SKILLS_SUCCESS;
    constructor(public payload: Skill[]) { }
}

export class ClearSkills implements Action {
    readonly type = CLEAR_SKILLS;
}

// create skill
export const CREATE_SKILL = '[Skills Section] Create Skill';
export const CREATE_SKILL_FAIL = '[Skills Section] Create Skill Fail';
export const CREATE_SKILL_SUCCESS = '[Skills Section] Create Skill Success';

export class CreateSkill implements Action {
    readonly type = CREATE_SKILL;
    constructor(public payload: Skill) { }
}

export class CreateSkillFail implements Action {
    readonly type = CREATE_SKILL_FAIL;
    constructor(public payload: any) { }
}

export class CreateSkillSuccess implements Action {
    readonly type = CREATE_SKILL_SUCCESS;
    constructor(public payload: Skill) { }
}

// update skill
export const UPDATE_SKILL = '[Skills Section] Update Skill';
export const UPDATE_SKILL_FAIL = '[Skills Section] Update Skill Fail';
export const UPDATE_SKILL_SUCCESS = '[Skills Section] Update Skill Success';

export class UpdateSkill implements Action {
    readonly type = UPDATE_SKILL;
    constructor(public payload: Skill) { }
}

export class UpdateSkillFail implements Action {
    readonly type = UPDATE_SKILL_FAIL;
    constructor(public payload: any) { }
}

export class UpdateSkillSuccess implements Action {
    readonly type = UPDATE_SKILL_SUCCESS;
    constructor(public payload: Skill) { }
}

// remove skill
export const REMOVE_SKILL = '[Skills Section] Remove Skill';
export const REMOVE_SKILL_FAIL = '[Skills Section] Remove Skill Fail';
export const REMOVE_SKILL_SUCCESS = '[Skills Section] Remove Skill Success';

export class RemoveSkill implements Action {
    readonly type = REMOVE_SKILL;
    constructor(public payload: Skill) { }
}

export class RemoveSkillFail implements Action {
    readonly type = REMOVE_SKILL_FAIL;
    constructor(public payload: any) { }
}

export class RemoveSkillSuccess implements Action {
    readonly type = REMOVE_SKILL_SUCCESS;
    constructor(public payload: Skill) { }
}

// set Selected skill id
export const SET_SELECTED_SKILL_ID = '[Skills Section] Set Selected Skill Id';
export const CLEAR_SELECTED_SKILL_ID = '[Skills Section] Clear Selected Skill Id';

export class SetSelectedSkillId implements Action {
    readonly type = SET_SELECTED_SKILL_ID;
    constructor(public payload: string) { }
}

export class ClearSelectedSkillId implements Action {
    readonly type = CLEAR_SELECTED_SKILL_ID;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// action types
export type SkillsAction =
    | LoadSkills
    | LoadSkillsFail
    | LoadSkillsSuccess
    | ClearSkills
    | CreateSkill
    | CreateSkillFail
    | CreateSkillSuccess
    | UpdateSkill
    | UpdateSkillFail
    | UpdateSkillSuccess
    | RemoveSkill
    | RemoveSkillFail
    | RemoveSkillSuccess
    | SetSelectedSkillId
    | ClearSelectedSkillId;
```

is there any way I can wrap this entire thing into a factory function that generates the exact same piece of code, accepting a name parameter and replacing the word 'Skill' with that param?

I've tried using decorators but that failed really quick then I tried to realize what it what is type and class in javascript and understood that's all functions so maybe the solution lies somewhere there.

is there an equivelant to reflection in JS, maybe that can do the trick?

Comment: Something that may interest you: https://github.com/guptasanchit90/ngrx-gen

Comment: its pretty much the same as me copy-pasting the same code over and over

Comment: Yeah, it's just a time saver. I though maybe you could glean some ideas from the code.

Comment: Something else may you may find interesting: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/schematics/action.md. And: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/schematics/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the exact same issue with NGRX - too much repetetive boilerplate code for actions as well as for reducers.

you can generate classes named dynamically like this:

```
const ClassFactory = (className) => {
    const obj = {};
    obj[className] = class { };
    return obj[className];
};

const classA = ClassFactory('classA');
```

Comment: thanks a lot, just realized that I can generate the entire object and just return the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using typescript you could checkout the `ts-action` npm module.

Basic Usage:

```
// without payload
import { action } from "ts-action";
const Foo = action("FOO");
store.dispatch(new Foo());

// with payload
import { action, payload } from "ts-action";
const Foo = action("FOO", payload<{ foo: number }>());
store.dispatch(new Foo({ foo: 42 }));
```

Documentation: https://github.com/cartant/ts-action

NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-action

Comment: nice library, but then again ill have to copy paste the entire code for 3 different entities because the const names cant be dynamic